# How to monkeypatch a Python class for an entire Django application?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

The main permission checking methods in Django REST Framework, `BasePermission`'s `has_permission` and `has_permission`, both [return `True`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6750), effectively making any permission checking allow by default. Since this is counter to a security mindset and [OWASP recommendations](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Positive_security_model) I would like to fix the implementation locally before reporting a bug. I could fix it for my own classes by subclassing `BasePermission` but I want to ensure that *every* subclass of `BasePermission` used anywhere does deny by default. Can I replace the functionality of these two methods for *every* subclass in my Django system without actually patching the `BasePermission` implementation?

To be clear, I am not trying to do this for testing purposes.

Comment: I would suggest patching Django REST framework and using your own version of the package while your bug/pull request is handled? This is a much safer approach than trying to monkey patch every instance.

Comment: @Tim Which instances? Surely there's only one in a Django application?

Comment: Your questing mentioned you want to change the behaviour of every subclass of `BasePermission` I am assuming you have many of these and therefore many instances of these subclasses. Again, I'd strongly suggest patching `BasePermission` and then building your own version of the package. I've done this while waiting for my pull requests to be included in a new release of Paramiko to fix a bug that was affecting production.

Comment: OK, cheers! Can do. I'll leave this open in case anyone suggests a way to patch these methods out globally.

Comment: Something else to consider is patching the source package is far less complex and simple than reliably applying an application wide monkey patch.

Comment: @Tim From having to maintain a custom Linux distro at another job I think I can only disagree. The actual patching is trivial, but building is often not, and keeping a patch in sync with the original repo "forever" if the maintainer doesn't want my changes is a massive pain.

Comment: The package build process is just `python setup.py bdist_wheel`. However, the clue is in the name, a monkey *patch* also requires you to keep your patches in sync with the upstream repo on top of the complexities of monkey patching.